# call a parameterized function binded with a angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I  created a angular directive for calling a method in my parent controller which accepts a parameter(true/false)
In my parent controller there a method

```
   app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope){ 

     $scope.myMethod = function(val) {
       alert(val)

     };
});
```

in my directive

```
app.directive('confirmBox',function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div>' +

            '<button ng-click="controlfunc(true)">Yes</button>' + 
            '<button ng-click="controlfunc(false)">No</button>' + 
         '</div>',
        scope: {

            controlfunc: '&funcattribute',

        },
        controller: function($scope) {                  
        }
    };
});
```

and the html code is

```
 <confirm-box  funcattribute="myMethod()" ></confirm-box>
```

When I click on the button Im getting 'undefined'

[PLUNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/jlgI1XzOyKJMJ0Gsd9tG?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a quite common task when writing custom directives and it's always a little bit tricky to remember how and where to define the argument name and how tool call the callback. From https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

> Often it's desirable to pass data from the isolate scope via an expression to the parent scope, this can be done by passing a map of local variable names and values into the expression wrapper fn. For example, the hideDialog function takes a message to display when the dialog is hidden. This is specified in the directive by calling close({message: 'closing for now'})

For your example, you have to modify the argument expression to

```
<confirm-box  funcattribute="myMethod(value)"></confirm-box>
```

and call the callback like this:

```
<button ng-click="controlfunc({ value : true })">Yes</button>
<button ng-click="controlfunc({ value : false })">No</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/so8sfryv/1/

Answer (score 1):

The thing with `&` is that you're not passing the function. Once you call the function `controlfunc` in the directive the provided function in the attribute is called, ie `myMethod()`. So you're not actually calling `myMethod` when calling `controlfunc`, only telling it to call the method provided. And the provided method `myMethod()` does not have any parameters, which is why you're seeing undefined.

You could `$emit` an event from the child-scope and listen on the parent-scope, to see the result. I edited the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/JBmxCqdjMvzlP468OiZl?p=preview) to show this method

Answer (score 0):

This is fundamentally wrong. There might be a way to do this, but you really shouldn't.

```
angular.module('MyApp', []);
angular.module('MyApp')
    .controller('ConfirmController', [function() {
        var vm = this;
        vm.clickHandler = function(value) {
            alert(value);
        };
    }]);

angular.module('MyApp')
    .directive('confirmBox', [function() {
        return {
            scope: true,
            restrict: 'E',
            controller: 'ConfirmController',
            controllerAs: 'confirmCtrl',
            template:   '<div>'+
                            '<button ng-click="confirmCtrl.clickHandler(true)">Yes</button>'+
                            '<button ng-click="confirmCtrl.clickHandler(false)">No</button>'+
                        '</div>'
        };
    }]);
```

Because you haven't really specified what should be done, this is how you should work with controllers and directives.

I'm guessing this isn't really what you wanted or needed, but you need to use a function in multiple controllers? If that's the case, than you should use a service.

Short and simple, a directive should only define the directive and the different classes it needs.
A controller should only be used to get the data that should be shown within a directive.
All other logic should be handled in services.

*edit:* You should read [Papa Johns styleguide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide), it is a great resource.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering why do you need the myMethod() ? You can just add the controlfunction to your directive like so:

```
app.directive('confirmBox', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div>' +

      '<button ng-click="controlfunc(true)">Yes</button>' +
      '<button ng-click="controlfunc(false)">No</button>' +
      '</div>',

    controller: function($scope) {

      $scope.controlfunc = function(val) {
        alert(val);
        $scope.funcattribute = val;
      }

    }
  };
});
```